# how make bootable usb flashdrive of Xubuntu to later be burned to a cd

Tags: system-installation, system

I am extremely new to Lenux and flavors. Have old laptop with win/xp sp3. Want a light wieght operating system Xubuntu to run on it. I have a 7gb actually 7.45gb on a flashdrive and need to know how to do a bootable flashdrive with install files on it. This same image would also be needed on a cd that someone will burn for me at a later time. i'm trying to get everything i would need on that cd for this older laptop to boot and install Xubuntu. Can you help. the laptop does not have usb capability. 1200 Mhz processor pentium. i am at Al1960@netzero.com

Comment: Once you  download the ISO, you can use [Yumi](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/), or [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create the USB bootable.

Answer (score 1):

you can download the xubuntu iso from their website. the same CD-image(iso) file can be use to create USB bootable and boot-CD. To make a bootable USB, use the "startup disk creator". to burn the iso as boot-CD, use any burning programs such as xburn or brasearo

Answer (score 0):

The downloadable .ISO file is the one you'll use to install from, simply burning this as a disk will mean you can install from it. The same file will be used in your bootable USB. If you're downloading the .ISO file from your Windows laptop, you'll need somewhere else to store the file which you want your friend to burn to disk, once you've made your bootable USB.

I've found that a free utility called [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) is my personal favourite to create bootable USBs on a Windows machine, it's reliable, very simple to use, and it also claims to be the quickest.

If you're just using the USB to transport the .ISO file, you don't need to create a bootable USB, just put the file on there, and burn it to disk once you're at your friend's.